# How to resolve Binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Got a user control defined as follows:

```
    public partial class EveBlueprintsGrid : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty BlueprintListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EveBlueprints",
        typeof(EveBlueprintList),
        typeof(EveBlueprintsGrid));

    public EveBlueprintList EveBlueprints
    {
        get { return (EveBlueprintList)GetValue(BlueprintListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlueprintListProperty, value); }
    }
```

with XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BlueprintsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EveBlueprints.Blueprints, ElementName=uc}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

With the calling XAML:

```
<Blueprints:EveBlueprintsGrid Grid.Column="1"  EveBlueprints="{Binding Blueprints}"/>
```

I am getting the "A Binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."  When I look at the calling XAML.
EveBlueprints contains property Blueprints which is an ObservableCollection.

What's interesting is I have an almost exact copy of this on another object which isn't giving me the errors I'm seeing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As a note, there is a naming convention, according to which the identifier field of your dependency property should be named `EveBlueprintsProperty`.

Comment: Naming convention aside, which I will update :)